# Being indecisive to report the immediate manager to HR manager before leaving the company

Tags: communication, human-resources, ethics, manager, unprofessional-behavior

I have been working for a company in South East Asia for the last 8 months. The company is large with poor sense of organization (it's very chaotic, but I like it as I get to work with some interesting projects).

My immediate manager is someone from overseas. He is a bully to every person who works for him, but most people don't have guts to go against him for one reason:

- Everyone who works for him has been hired directly from
  another country (the Manager's home country) and they often speak English poorly and don't know about their rights in the company. (They just know programming)

Some of the his behavior has disturbed me personally such as asking me to work over weekend while there was no need for that, or not allowing me to speak when we were in a discussion with some other managers. (He is a control freak)

**I have recently heard from few sources that he takes the salary for the first month of all the poor people he hires as his commission. He arranges this with them during the Skype interview and he only refers them to HR for further hiring processes if they agree.**

On one hand I was shocked to hear such thing, on the other hand knowing how unethical he is made it easy for me to digest.

I am now leaving the company and I'm on very good terms with the company's HR manager as he has received few positive reviews about me from clients and counterparts.

I am thinking about reporting what he has done to me and what I have heard he has done to others to the HR manager before I leave, but I am not sure if this is a right thing to do or if I am just being unethical like him but in a different way?

I hope to hear your point of views...

Answer (score 14):

> I am thinking to report what he has done to me and what I have heard
>   he has done to others to the HR manager before I leave, but I am not
>   sure if this is a right thing to do Or I am just being unethical like
>   him but in a different way?

The actions taken by this manager not only sounds *unethical*, but is most **likely illegal**.  Definitely report them on your way out the door.

HR is there to protect the company.  If the HR department has any brains they will investigate and take appropriate action.

Comment: The only thing to be wary of when reporting him is that you might be asked why you didn't report something so unethical sooner. It sounds like in this instance the OP learned about it fairly recently though, so hopefully it won't be a problem.